# For FTP warehouses, what time zone is the daily schedule based on?

Tags: ftp, timezone

When setting up an FTP warehouse, what time zone is used for the scheduled run times?

Comment: Hi.  There's not enough detail in your question to identify much of anything that would help another user understand what you are asking about.  An "FTP warehouse" is a pretty broad term.  If you are referring to a specific product, please name that product and tag it appropriately.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center.  Also, your question may be better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing, the scheduled run time will be dependent on the timezone configured within Basic Info of the warehouse settings.